# How do I display an image from numpy array of dimension [10000, 32, 32, 3]?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy array of dimension [10000, 32, 32, 3] containing pixel values, I want to display one image out of it to check if it correct.

I have tried to use:

```
plt.imshow(images)
plt.show
```

But I get an error :
TypeError: Invalid shape (10000, 32, 32, 3) for image data.

So I tried to select one image and display it

```
plt.imshow(images[1])
plt.show
```

For this I get no output.

How do I display an image from this array?

Edit: 'images' is the name of the numpy array with the pixel values

Comment: let's exclude trivial things first, are you calling `plt.show()` without parentheses? how are you running your code? (python, ipython, jupyter, ...)

Comment: Just saw that I had missed the paratheses. That fixed it :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
plt.imshow(images[1])
plt.show()
```